# Bootstrap glyphicon alignment not showing on IE

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've this button using bootstrap classes

```
<button class="btn btn-default" style="padding: 6px 0px; border-radius: 18px; width: 36px; height: 36px; text-align: center; line-height: 1.42; font-size: 12px;" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span></button>
```

With firefox the symbol is center aligned.
But with IE the symbol doesn't even show, it seams to be hiding on the left...

I've set text-align:center but it doesn't work either.

How can this be fixed for IE?

EDIT:
I'm using IE 11.0 without compatibility on.

Comment: Which IE version, and what rendering mode is it using?

Comment: any example, helps us to track actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Height / width, padding, etc. attributes do not work right on buttons unless you give them display:inline-block or display:block. Buttons, links etc. are display:inline by default. Once you set that, you can align the text inside.

Comment: Tried to shuffle some of those properties but still the glyphicon shows with Firefox and not in IE.

Comment: What server are you serving it from, e.g. IIS, apache etc.? It's possible the server is not sending the correct MIME type for the font.